# What happens to the data in an EC2's ephemeral storage when it terminates?

Tags: amazon-ec2

When an EC2 instance terminates, what physically happens to the data that was on ephemeral storage?

Assuming that I don't explicitly delete anything before the instance terminates, do I need to worry about someone being able to read the data left behind?  Does EC2 automatically destroy (zero out) data left on ephemeral storage, or somehow ensure that it is inaccessible?

Comment: If it's sensitive data, zero it out, regardless of whether it's instance storage or EBS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Assuming that I don't explicitly delete anything before the instance
>   terminates, do I need to worry about someone being able to read the
>   data left behind?

No.

> Does EC2 automatically destroy (zero out) data left on ephemeral
>   storage, or somehow ensure that it is inaccessible?

Yes, both ephemeral and EBS volumes go into a pool to be scrubbed before those blocks appear again in the "free" pool.  That said, if your data is of extrordinary sensitivity, you probably want to take matters into your own hands and scrub these volumes yourself before terminating.

For more information how they handle EBS volumes, see page 18 of the [AWS Security Whitepaper](https://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/aws-security-best-practices/). I'm unable to find equivalent documentation on ephemeral volumes at the moment.

Comment: Of note: "If you have proceduresrequiring that all data be wiped via a specificmethod,such asthose detailed inDoD5220.22‐M
(“National Industrial Security ProgramOperating Manual “) orNIST 800‐88 (“Guidelinesfor Media Sanitization”), you
have the ability to do so on Amazon EBS. You should conduct a specialized wipe procedure priorto deleting the volume
for compliance with your established requirements."

Comment: The document doesn't talk about a free pool. Do you have any proof that Amazon does what you claim here?

Comment: found it: Amazon EBS volumes are presented to you as raw unformatted block devices that have been wiped prior to being made
available for use. Wiping occurs immediately before reuse so that you can be assured that the wipe process completed.  https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-security-whitepaper.pdf

Comment: @Jonathan, EBS is different from ephemeral disks. AWS do say ephemeral disks are erased on instance stop or terminate, on this page http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html#lifecycle-differences